# Python Convert datetime[ns] to datetime[D]

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas

So I've used to_datetime() to convert a string that looks like this '23 Jan 2015' into a datetime that looks like this '2015-01-23' but its dtype is datetime[ns] instead of datetime[D].  How do I convert it to datetime[D] instead, during the process of using to_datetime() or after? Thanks.

Comment: pandas keeps datetimes internally as ``datetime64[ns]``. This type of conversion not needed. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: If you want just a date instead of datetime for some calculations then if you're running a 0.15.0 and above pandas version you can access the date attribute so `df['date'].dt.date` will return a date

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could use strptime() and date()

For example:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('23 Jan 2015', "%d %b %Y").date()
```

returns '2015-01-23'